INSERT INTO SELECT each row with different external value
I have a query which is working properly:
INSERT INTO t1 (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) 
SELECT COL_1, 'external value', COL_3 
FROM t2 
WHERE COL_4 IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')

So, 'external value' goes to each row in t1.
The question is: How can I add different 'external value' to rows? For example, the first row has 'ext val 1', the second row has 'ext val 2' and so on...
Is there any solution to this approach?
THX.
Currently, I have no any idea for INSERT INTO SELECT, but if possible I do not want to switch to INSERT INTO VALUES ... Additional info, the target DB is MYSQL.

Where do the external values come from? Are they just hard-coded, or generated or input from somewhere? Do they arrive as a list? Do they have a relationship to the other inserted data, or is it literally just an arbitrary sequence where you want the first external value on the 1st row inserted, and the second external value on the 2nd row inserted, regardless of what else that row contains? (Bearing in mind you're not ordering your SELECT, so the order the rows will be selected and inserted isn't guaranteed!). It wasn't clear, but such details might affect the precise solutions available.

@ADyson Great thoughts! You pushed me further towards the solution, which I didn't want to see. Of course there is a relation between externals and data in 'WHERE' clause. So this approch will never going to work. I won't delete the post, just in case it points someone else in the right direction. Thanks again!

No problem. If you found the solution yourself please do post an Answer in the box below - your'e allowed to answer your own question normally

INSERT INTO t1 (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) 
SELECT t2.COL_1, external_values.external_value, t2.COL_3 
FROM t2 
JOIN ( SELECT 1, 'value 1' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2, 'value 2' UNION ALL
       SELECT 3, 'value 3' UNION ALL
       SELECT 4, 'value 4'  
       ) AS external_values (col_4, external_value) USING (col_4)

fiddle
The values can be provided in any other rowset form - for example, as an output of JSON_TABLE function.

try this
INSERT INTO t1 (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3)
SELECT
  COL_1,
  CONCAT('ext val ', (@i:= @i+1)) AS 'ext_val',
  COL_3
FROM
  t2,
  (SELECT @i:=0) AS i WHERE COL_4 IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')

